# How do I get rid of this hyperlink cut-off during dynamic breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, hyperlink

I have built a website that works perfectly, but I am experience a very odd problem that I can not fix no matter how much I play with the code.

Each page in this site has a side-menu on the left. The following is an example:

http://mtschools.net/cadences

It works fine in full window viewing, but when you re-size the window to <= 768px, the side-menu moves to the center top (as it should), but the bottom link of the side-menu, in this case "Interrupted Cadence," stops working.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Many Thanks.

Comment: With which browser(s) are you seeing this behavior? It looks fine on win7 chrome.

Comment: I am so happy you mentioned this. I am using Win10 Chrome where the problem persists, but I have just try MS Edge and it works fine.

Comment: My Chrome is up to date. Could you think of any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put a higher z-index at the `left-menubar` div.

For example:

```
<div id="left-menubar" style="z-index: 99999;">
```

It worked when I tested on my Chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the definite fix!